# The best practice for app launch time duration Android

Tags: android, performance, analytics

I need to measure the App Launch time. What I am thinking of is to have a static variable of the current time on Application onCreate and in the 1st fragment of the app I subtract this variable onActivityCreated. But I do not think this is the best practice. Is there a lib or a call that provide such result?. Appreciated your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool such as `TraceView` to help debug the application and profile the performance. It's basically a a graphical viewer for your execution logs.

To start the Traceview tool:

1. Start the Android Device Monitor.
2. In the Android Device Monitor tool bar, click DDMS and select a process.
3. Click the Start Method Profiling icon to start method profiling.
4. After the profiling is complete, click the Stop Method Profiling icon to display the traceview.

There is more information on how to use `TraceView` here:

http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html

Comment: I want to have it in code so I can send it via analytics.